# How to get text object from a html table using selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I have a part of html file as below

```
<div><pre> <b>Home:</b>   28-12   <b>Road:</b>   23-16   <b>ExtrInn:</b> 2-5 
<b>vsRHP:</b>  38-18   <b>vsLHP:</b>  13-10   <b>1-Run:</b>  17-5 
<b>vsEast:</b> 12-8    <b>vsCntrl:</b> 7-5    <b>vsWest:</b> 26-13 <b>IL:</b> 6-2 

<strong>Last 10 Games</strong>
Gm# Date &amp; Box   Opp W/L Score      Record   Place/GB
 79 <A CLASS=CL HREF="/boxes/NYA/NYA201606290.shtml">Wed, Jun 29</a>  @<A CLASS=CL HREF="/teams/NYY/2016_sched.shtml">NYY</A>  L   7-9       51-28  1st  9.0 up
 78 <A CLASS=CL HREF="/boxes/NYA/NYA201606280.shtml">Tue, Jun 28</a>  @<A CLASS=CL HREF="/teams/NYY/2016_sched.shtml">NYY</A>  W   7-1       51-27  1st 10.0 up
 77 <A CLASS=CL HREF="/boxes/NYA/NYA201606270.shtml">Mon, Jun 27</a>  @<A CLASS=CL HREF="/teams/NYY/2016_sched.shtml">NYY</A>  W   9-6       50-27  1st 10.0 up
 76 <A CLASS=CL HREF="/boxes/TEX/TEX201606260.shtml">Sun, Jun 26</a>   <A CLASS=CL HREF="/teams/BOS/2016_sched.shtml">BOS</A>  W   6-2       49-27  1st 10.0 up
 75 <A CLASS=CL HREF="/boxes/TEX/TEX201606250.shtml">Sat, Jun 25</a>   <A CLASS=CL HREF="/teams/BOS/2016_sched.shtml">BOS</A>  W  10-3       48-27  1st  9.0 up
 74 <A CLASS=CL HREF="/boxes/TEX/TEX201606240.shtml">Fri, Jun 24</a>   <A CLASS=CL HREF="/teams/BOS/2016_sched.shtml">BOS</A>  L   7-8       47-27  1st  9.0 up
 73 <A CLASS=CL HREF="/boxes/TEX/TEX201606220.shtml">Wed, Jun 22</a>   <A CLASS=CL HREF="/teams/CIN/2016_sched.shtml">CIN</A>  W   6-4       47-26  1st 10.0 up
 72 <A CLASS=CL HREF="/boxes/TEX/TEX201606210.shtml">Tue, Jun 21</a>   <A CLASS=CL HREF="/teams/CIN/2016_sched.shtml">CIN</A>  L   2-8       46-26  1st  9.5 up
 71 <A CLASS=CL HREF="/boxes/TEX/TEX201606200.shtml">Mon, Jun 20</a>   <A CLASS=CL HREF="/teams/BAL/2016_sched.shtml">BAL</A>  W   4-3       46-25  1st  9.5 up
 70 <A CLASS=CL HREF="/boxes/SLN/SLN201606190.shtml">Sun, Jun 19</a>  @<A CLASS=CL HREF="/teams/STL/2016_sched.shtml">STL</A>  W   5-4       45-25  1st  8.5 up
<b>Last 10:</b> 7-3    <b>Last 20:</b>15-5    <b>Last 30:</b>23-7 
</pre></div>
```

Anyone know how to get infos in Last 10 Last 20 and Last 30 using Selenium Python ?

Results should be 7-3, 15-5 and 23-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That HTML is... something. The text you want isn't inside of any localized tag. You are going to have to grab all the text inside the outer `DIV` to find what you want. You can use regex or just parse it. The code below should be close.

```
alltext = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("div").text // locator needs to be more specific
results = re.findall('(Last \d{2}:\s*\d+-\d+)', alltext)
print results
```

The regex is looking for "Last " + 2 digits + ":" + 0 or more spaces + 1 or more digits + "-" + 1 or more digits. `findall()` will return all instances of that regex in the string so it should return all three.

[Python regex info](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)